# I'll See You First

Tags: riddle, rhyme

America out front, with Britain behind,
The king of the land proudly stood,
From its fortress way up high,
Its whole half more understood.

Very loyal and laser sharp eyes,
If the other falls, it'll go it alone,
Fear the air and fear the land,
As it sits on its perch with its heart of stone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it have anything to do with a:

> Gryphon/Gryffin? America's national animal is an eagle and Britain's is a lion so something that has an eagle head and lion rear. You also mention 'king of the land' (lion), 'laser sharp eyes', and 'perch' (eagle) which also support the idea.

Comment: @ James Coyle, indeed. All the lines support it, so please continue. (having trouble with the response to your name.)

Comment: @JamesCoyle Great answer. +1,  Line 6 could be a reference to a sketchy fact on [Wikipedia - In legend, ******** not only mated for life, but if either partner died, then the other would continue the rest of its life alone, never to search for a new mate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griffin)

Comment: @BrentHackers, it is. Good job.

Comment: @BrentHackers, after reviewing the wikipedia article, I concur that this particular 'fact' may be sketchy, it does support the puzzle in an obvious way, and should give a puzzler ample reason to believe they were on the right track, namely being on what is commonly the first and sometimes only stop for supporting information, i.e. wikipedia. There are several other sites that support this 'fact'. Of course, since I haven't spoken to a griffin, I could only go with what I read. :) I didn't include it as a leading clue, just a reinforcing one.