# I shall receive no response

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am a powerful weapon, per se,
>   I can be loaded just fire away,
>   I can be pointed to stab and dismay.
>
> Sometimes I'll come from both sides at once,
>   A master of rhetoric I shall receive no response,
>   As I'm at the end I know you must see,
>   What is it that I must be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you'd be a

> Question

I am a powerful weapon, per se,

> Questions can be powerful.

I can be loaded just fire away,

> There's the loaded question approach.

I can be pointed to stab and dismay.

> Pointed/Poignant question.

Sometimes I'll come from both sides at once,

> In spanish a question mark is in front and back.

A master of rhetoric I shall receive no response,

> Rhetorical questions don't require a response.

As I'm at the end I know you must see,
What is it that I must be?

> At the end of this riddle and questions is the question mark.

Comment: Very good! And very fast! My original answer for the "both sides" bit was indeed the ¿Spanish question? syntax, although I realize question mark and question are different so I was also accepting "two-sided" questions. And yes again I was referring to the fact that at the end of this riddle you will "see" that "I'm at the end" being both the question/mark at the last line of the riddle.

Comment: Well done!  Being a fluent Spanish speaker, I'm a little ashamed that I didn't include that in my answer!

Comment: @Reibello, bum deal. :) I'm not, but I'm from Texas, so I can speak a little (and studied a bit). Good riddle DasBeasto.

Comment: @DasBeasto, take a look at mine and let me know what you think. http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/37833/25802

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> A question

I can be loaded just fire away

> You can ask a [Loaded Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question) to limit your responses.

I can be pointed to stab and dismay.

> A pointed question is a very direct question, which can feel like an attack (stab).

Sometimes I'll come from both sides at once,

> Some of the best questions don't have answers.  Only more questions.

A master of rhetoric I shall receive no response

> A [Rhetorical Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) is a question that needs no response.

and finally,

As I'm at the end I know you must see,

> Question marks come at the end of a sentence (in English.)

Comment: +1 Very good work, John was just a hair faster and got some of the alternative intentions of a few hints. I would have accepted this if not for his.